# Stop automatic reforwarding to mobile site when laptop is using Galaxy S3 Hotspot

Tags: android, mobile-phone

I am using my Galaxy S3 to create a wifi hotspot for my laptop.

Unfortunately, when I navigate to some sites, because the traffic is going through my phone, the website that I am going to thinks I'm on a mobile device and returns only the awful mobile version of the website - even though I'm on a laptop.

How can I get the full desktop version of the website on my computer in this arrangement?

Comment: For Firefox, there's [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/). Don't know if it will solve your problem, but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Can you give an example of a website that does this? I've never had a similiar problem with my hotspot.

Comment: One example: yad2.co.il

Comment: Usually this is the setting from the browser rather than from the phone that is providing internet access. The server should not really see the phone (or care about the IP it is connecting from), and simply serve the page accordingly. But when the server finds out your "User-Agent" shows that you are using Firefox mobile (or other mobile browser) it will serve you the mobile page. Check your browser setting. Or use a different browser. Maybe you had set up your browser to use some sort of "bandwidth limited" mode to save data?

Comment: @Darius It's definitely the phone causing it, because the laptop on any other network displays the content perfectly as a desktop should. It's only when I use the phone as a mobile hotspot that this happens